# Scale a number & create 100 points with larger gaps at the top end of the scale

Tags: math, logic

Random question I want to be able to take a number for arguments sake 1000, and scale it up to a maximum point. Creating 100 points along the way.

I want the scale to become more steep as the scale increases and the jump between the points to become larger.

I know this can be done with simple maths, but can't think of the correct approach/name to research.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the fact that pow(0,order) = 0 and pow(1, order) = 1. Something like:

```
        double min = 1000;
        double max = 2000;
        double range = max - min;
        double nPoints = 100;
        double order = 2;
        for (double norm = 0; norm < 1.0; norm += 1.0 / (nPoints - 1.0))
        {
            double val = min + Math.Pow(norm, order) * range;   
        }
```

will create values between min and max, and the spacing between the values will increase. You can make the effect greater by using higher order values.

Comment: Thanks for this chaz. I'll run some tests on it today and see what i get.